# How to filter second GridViewDataComboBoxColumn dropdown item from selection of first GridViewDataComboBoxColumn inside ASPxGridView

Tags: devexpress

There are two GridViewDataComboBoxColumn columns inside my ASPxGridView, Need to know that Selection of first GridViewDataComboBoxColumn dropdown item should filter the second GridViewDataComboBoxColumn item before pupulating data.

For example, If I choose 'India' from first GridViewDataComboBoxColumn then only India's cities must be populated in another GridViewDataComboBoxColumn dropdown using SqlDataSource.

My sample code:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ClientInstanceName="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ID="ASPxGridView1" DataSourceID="DSEXTagList" OnCellEditorInitialize="GridViewEXTags_CellEditorInitialize" KeyFieldName="ID;" OnRowInserting="GridViewEXTags_RowInserting" Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Caption="System" FieldName="System" VisibleIndex="1">
                            <PropertiesComboBox EnableCallbackMode="true" DataSourceID="DsSystem" TextField="SystemWithDescription" ValueField="System" NullDisplayText="Select System">
                            </PropertiesComboBox>
                        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Caption="Sub System" FieldName="SubSystem" VisibleIndex="2">
                            <PropertiesComboBox DataSourceID="DsSubSystem" TextField="SubSystemWithDescription" ValueField="SubSystem" NullDisplayText="Select Sub System">
                            </PropertiesComboBox>
                        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Actually I'm new in Asp.net DevExpress technologies. Please somebody let me know what should I do in this case and fire event on selection of GridViewDataComboBoxColumn item in code side.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/CascadingComboBoxes.aspx) demo to see (play) this approach in action. See the demo's description for more information:

- For the "parent" combobox column: handle the client-side "SelectedIndexChanged" event,
- Call the "child: combobox column/editor callback via the client-side "PerformCallback" method,
- Subscribe and Handle the "child" comobobox "Callback" event and reload its data.